# how can i test word cloud system?

Tags: testing, word-cloud

i need help about testing a word cloud system.

**The system:** the system has 3 word clouds visualization (A, B and C). The word cloud A and B are the output of the dataset A and dataset B, respectively. The word cloud C is the operation result between word cloud A and B.

**The question:** how can i test that scenario? Anyone can give me some example of test cases  and test method to that system. How can i ensure that system is working correctly?